# Help solving recursive relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

$x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} + 20x_n + n^2 + 5^n \text{ with } x_0 = 0 \text{ and } x_1 = 0$

How would you solve this recursive relation? I have the homogenous solution, but am having issues with the in-homogenous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generating functions. Define $X(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} x_n z^n$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$ to get after recognizing some sums:
$$
\frac{X(z) - x_0 - x_1 z}{z^2}
  = \frac{X(z) - x_0}{z} + 20 X(z)
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 z^n
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} 5^n z^n
$$
For the troublesome sums remaining:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 z^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} 
       \left(z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \right) \\
  &= \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^3} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} 5^n z^n
  &= \frac{1}{1 - 5 z}
\end{align}
Plug all this in, solve for $X(z)$ as partial fractions:
\begin{align}
X(z)
  &= \frac{z^2 - 2 z^3 - z^4 - 6 z^5}
          {1 - 9 z + 6 z^2 + 126 z^3 - 339 z^4 + 315 z^5 - 100 z^6} \\
  &= \frac{1}{45} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - 5 z)^2}
       - \frac{313}{12960} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 5 z}
       + \frac{98}{10125} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 4 z}
       - \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3}
       + \frac{29}{200} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
       - \frac{211}{4000} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
You want the coefficient of $z^n$ in this, which can be computed term-by-term by using the generatlized binomial theorem, for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ it gives:
$$
(1 + u)^{-m}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
$$
Also note that the binomial coefficients are just $m - 1$ degree polynomials in $k$.

Answer (score 0):

For the $n^2$ part you have $An^2+Bn+C$ for a specific solution - equate coefficients.

For the $5^n$ part you need to look at $Dn^{r}5^n$ where $r$ is the multiplicity of $5$ as a root of $x^2-x-20=0$ - here you already have $5^n$ in your solution of the homogeneous part.

Comment: for the homogeneous solution i got 0. Would that be correct?

Comment: @jessV75 The homogeneous solution should be $E5^n+F(-4)^n$. You need to put the whole solution together before putting in the initial values $An^2+Bn+C+Dn5^n+E5^n+F(-4)^n$. $A,B,C,D$ will come out of the recurrence itself to deal with the inhomogeneous bit. $E,F$ will be determined by the two initial conditions. If you were solving the homogeneous equation with the given initial conditions you would get zero.